# Why are glues/adhesives made up of polymers?

Tags: polymers, adhesion

Why are glues/adhesives made up of polymers?
Can monomers be used to make an adhesive.

What is is about the fact that the molecules are stuck together in a chain that make them better/more useful as an adhesive?

Is it like its harder to push people over that are linking arms with other people?

Comment: As a side note, various monomers are known to *promote* adhesion. These monomers contain functional groups such as phosphate/carboxylic acids, silyl ethers, etc.